# Is there a way to change font of different lines using a multiline label?

Tags: c#, multiline

I'm currently trying to create a calculator, eventually it will be my own that will do algebraic math, however I'm knew to with creating a Form Application so I'm still learning. I'm trying to mimic the way the built in Microsoft calculator looks, I've created a label and enabled multiline, is there a way I can change font size, and text color for specific lines of the label?

I've searched around on google a little bit but I'm not entirely finding anything related exactly to my issue

I'm creating text on the second line using this

```
result.Text = Environment.NewLine + "0";
```

So there's no confusion the 0 is placed on the second line, this is what is displayed when no numbers have been clicked or the calculator is cleared. When someone presses an operator such as +, or -, it clears the text on the second line so they can continue on with adding or subtracting the next number. I want the text on the top line to be the last number and operator they entered, but I want that number to be smaller and in a more gray color so they don't get confused.

Comment: Windows Calculator uses different *pieces* to render different elements. A Label doesn't support different Fonts. You can yourself layout different controls. Or you can use a RichTextBox. You probably prefer the first solution.

Comment: Even if Windows Calculator used a label (which it doesn't), what makes you think it would be a single label in multi-line mode (which can only be one font and color) instead of two single line labels (which could each have their own font and color)?

Comment: Or you can owner-draw the Label.